# For the specified object set a call to each of the functions C++

Tags: c++

I have the specified object `MyClass* x = new MyClass();` and class `MyClass`.

But I don't understand how to call three functions `Change1(MyClass m)`, `Change2(MyClass &m)`, `Change3(MyClass* m)` in Main Method.

I have problem with pointers.

```
namespace ConsoleApp11 
{
    class MyClass 
    {
        public:
            int x;

            MyClass () { x = 0; } 
            void Change1 (MyClass m) { m.x = 1; } 
            void Change2 (MyClass & m) { m.x = 1; } 
            void Change3 (MyClass * m) { m->x = 1; } 
    };

    class Program 
    {
        static void main () 
        {
            MyClass * x = new MyClass ();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This looks like C++, not C#.

Comment: @juharr Ok. It's `C++` because of semicolon after `public` but why to use `static void main` when it can be moved outside a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class MyClass 
    {
        public:
            int x;

            MyClass () { x = 0; } 
            void Change1 (MyClass m) { m.x = 1; } 
            void Change2 (MyClass & m) { m.x = 1; } 
            void Change3 (MyClass * m) { m->x = 1; } 
    };

    class Program 
    {
        static void main()
        {
            MyClass* obj = new MyClass();

            obj->Change1(*obj);
            obj->Change2(*obj);
            obj->Change3(obj);
        }
    };
}
```

But I have some questions too:

- why to create `main` as `static` inside a `class`called Program when it can be created outside of that `class`?
- why to create methods as non-static when another object is passed to them as an argument?

Let me present you with somewhat better solution:

```
namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class MyClass 
    {
        public:
            int x;

            MyClass () { x = 0; }

            void ChangeMe() { this->x = 1; }

            static void ChangeOther1(MyClass m) {m.x = 1;}
            static void ChangeOther2(MyClass& m) {m.x = 1;}
            static void ChangeOther3(MyClass* m) {m->x = 1;}
    };

    int main()
    {
        MyClass* obj = new MyClass();

        // non-static
        obj->ChangeMe();
        (*obj).ChangeMe();

        // static
        MyClass::ChangeOther1(*obj);
        MyClass::ChangeOther2(*obj);
        MyClass::ChangeOther3(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing code. I'm only a beginner, so I'll continue to handle it.